# JSTL: Nested forEach loop. Contents not displaying in individual rows

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, jstl

```
    <table>
        <c:forEach var="moviesFromAGenre" items="${moviesFromRandomGenres}">
            <tr>
            <c:forEach var="movie" items="${moviesFromAGenre}">
                <td>
                    <a href="getMovie?selected=<c:out value="${movie[0]}"/>" >
                        <img src="<c:out value="${movie[1]}"/>"  WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="300" BORDER="0"/>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

The content is displaying like this:

1

2

3

4

5

...

Instead of:

1 2 3 4 5

5 6 7 8 9

I've tried using < br> after the first forEach and it produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to use `<br>` as you are using a `<table>`  this can be formatted to your requirements by changing the positioning of `<tr>`

Use Browser development tools to inspect the html that is generated

Comment: I inspected and it's generating a new table row for every entry despite the tr tag being outside the inner loop.

Comment: so maybe your source data is incorrect and you have 10 `moviesFromRandomGenres` with single `moviesFromAGenre` rather than (expected?) 2 `moviesFromRandomGenres` with 5 `moviesFromAGenre`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        <c:forEach var="moviesFromAGenre" items="${moviesFromRandomGenres}">
          <h:panelGrid columns="${moviesFromAGenre.size()}">
            <c:forEach var="movie" items="${moviesFromAGenre}">                  
                    <a href="getMovie?selected=<c:out value="${movie[0]}"/>" >
                        <img src="<c:out value="${movie[1]}"/>"  WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="300" BORDER="0"/>
                    </a>                   
            </c:forEach>
          </h:panelGrid>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: what on earth does panelGrid have to do with this question?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, We can solve the above issue by using that h:panelGrid, that is why I posted here.

Comment: But the OP has not indicated that he is using JSF or whatever

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I am just suggest him to use h:panelGrid because he already using c:forEach.